# How to get a SQL Query to combine two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some questions about a SQL query. I've a table called CUSTOMER with the following fields (name, city):

```
Juan   New York
Louis  Madrid
```

And another table called ASESOR with the following fields (name, city):

```
Michael   New York
Peter  Zurich
Dan   Madrid
```

I need a query that combines both tables where the city is the same.

**Expected result**:

```
Juan New York
Loius Madrid
Michael New York
Dan Madrid
```

Peter has to be out of the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` combined with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT name , city
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ASESOR a WHERE c.city= a.city)
UNION ALL
SELECT name , city
FROM ASESOR a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE c.city= a.city);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=12791cde4c15fdc0c32769e671c7f2d8)**

Output:

```
┌──────────┬──────────┐
│  name    │   city   │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│ Juan     │ New York │
│ Louis    │ Madrid   │
│ Michael  │ New York │
│ Dan      │ Madrid   │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```